# I writing a code for paranthesis checking but the complier show me these errors

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++17, c++14

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class stack
{
    
    public:
    int size;
    int top;
    char * arr;
};

int isempty(stack*ptr)
{   if (ptr->top==-1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
int isFull(stack*ptr)
{
    if (ptr->top==ptr->size-1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
    
    
}
void push(stack*ptr,char value)
{
    if(isFull(ptr))
    {
       cout<<"stack overflow";

    }
    else
    {
        ptr->top++;
        ptr->arr[ptr->top]=value;
        
        
    }
}

char pop(stack*ptr)
{
    if(isempty(ptr))
    {
        cout<<"Stack is empty";
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        char v=ptr->arr[ptr->top];
        ptr->top--;
        return v;
    }
    
}

int peek(stack*ptr,int i)
{
    if(ptr->top-i+1<0)
    {
        cout<<"invalid input";
    }
    else
    {
        return ptr->arr[ptr->top-i+1];
    }
    
}

int paranthesisamatch(char*exp)
{      stack*ptr;
       ptr->size=100;
       ptr->top=-1;
       ptr->arr=(char *)malloc(ptr->size * sizeof(char));


       for (int i = 0;exp[i]!="\0"; i++)
       {
           if(exp[i]=='(')
           {
               push(ptr,'(');
           }
           else if (exp[i]==')')
           {
               if (isempty(ptr))
               {
                   return  0;
               }
               pop(ptr);
               
           }
           
           
        {
    if (isempty(ptr))
        {
    return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char*exp= "8+(9*4)";
    if (paranthesisamatch(exp)))
    {
        cout<<"The paranthesis is matching";
    }
    cout<<"The paranthesis is not matching";
    
    return 0;
};
```

'Error'

```
C:\Users\91977\Desktop\C++>cd "c:\Users\91977\Desktop\C++\" && g++ tempCodeRunnerFile.cpp -o tempCodeRunnerFile && "c:\Users\91977\Desktop\C++\"tempCodeRunnerFile
tempCodeRunnerFile.cpp:12:13: error: reference to 'stack' is ambiguous
 int isempty(stack*ptr)
             ^~~~~
tempCodeRunnerFile.cpp:3:7: note: candidates are: class stack
 class stack
       ^~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\stack:61:0,  
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\mingw32\bits\stdc++.h:89,      
                 from tempCodeRunnerFile.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_stack.h:99:11: note:                 template<class _Tp, class _Sequence> class std::stack
     class stack
           ^~~~~
tempCodeRunnerFile.cp:12:19: error: 'ptr' was not declared in this scope
 int isempty(stack*ptr)
                   ^~~
```

Comment: You'll need to clean up the post, so it is readable.

Comment: Please reformat your post and ask question not only in title but in post itself with more details (what you’re trying to achieve, what you tried etc)

Comment: Don't `using namespace std;`, in particular not if you `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`

Comment: Tried to properly format your post, but you got all the markup in there, so neither form is really readable. You should take our [tour] and read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). This should explain everything.

Answer (score 1):

it seems your stack class has conflict with std::stack. because std already has stack class and your class has same name with standard library stack so in this case compiler dont know to use which stack so i recommend you to not use:

```
using namespace std;
```

because it's bad practice and also please dont include  **#include<bits/stdc++.h>** because it's bad practice too.

more information about **#include<bits/stdc++.h>** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H.).

but use std:: prefix with what class you want from std.